# How to get OLD values while writing Triggers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How can I  implement this script in sql server:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER after_update_animal AFTER UPDATE

ON Animal FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Animal_histo (
        id, 
        sexe, 
        date_naissance, 
        nom, 
        commentaires, 
        espece_id, 
        race_id, 
        mere_id, 
        pere_id, 
        disponible,

        date_histo, 
        utilisateur_histo, 
        evenement_histo)
    VALUES (
        OLD.id,
        OLD.sexe,
        OLD.date_naissance,
        OLD.nom,
        OLD.commentaires,
        OLD.espece_id,
        OLD.race_id,
        OLD.mere_id,
        OLD.pere_id,
        OLD.disponible,

        NOW(),
        CURRENT_USER(),
        'UPDATE');
END |

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The object name you are looking for is `deleted`.  Consider reading the documentation on triggers: [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql)

Comment: This looks like mysql rather than sqlserver are you trying to convert to sqlserver or is the question tagged incorrectly?

Answer (score 4):

The `deleted` table holds the previous values before the update, the `inserted` table holds the new ones. `For each row` can be ommited as this will do a batch operation.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_update_animal ON Animal AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Animal_histo (
        id, 
        sexe, 
        date_naissance, 
        nom, 
        commentaires, 
        espece_id, 
        race_id, 
        mere_id, 
        pere_id, 
        disponible,
        date_histo, 
        utilisateur_histo, 
        evenement_histo)
    SELECT
        OLD.id,
        OLD.sexe,
        OLD.date_naissance,
        OLD.nom,
        OLD.commentaires,
        OLD.espece_id,
        OLD.race_id,
        OLD.mere_id,
        OLD.pere_id,
        OLD.disponible,
        GETDATE(),
        SYSTEM_USER,
        'UPDATE'
    FROM
        deleted AS OLD

END
```